# What is the Evenstar necklace?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In Peter Jackson's *Lord of the Rings*, Arwen gives a jewel to Aragorn: the Evenstar necklace:

[image: Evenstar necklace]

Where did this jewel come from? Does it have any special powers or meaning?

Comment: I seem to recall Glorfindel leaving some sort of (green?) gem somewhere, as a sign, which someone finds, I seem to recall it was Aragorn. Since Arwen "replaced" Glorfindel in the movie, perhaps it is some vague reference?

Comment: @TLP. Glorfindel left a beryl on a bridge, as a token of safety.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think there is any special meaning to the necklace. It was invented for the movie and is never mentioned in the book. Arwen does give a necklace to Frodo after the war is over, but it is not referred to as "the Evenstar necklace" or anything else close.

I think the necklace accomplished the dual purpose of a set piece that helps to tell a story while also being a marketable piece of jewelry.

Comment: So, it have the power to bring wealth to the licensor.

Comment: just googling the necklace's name gives 80% shopping results.

Comment: @JustinC - Try googling Gandalf's staff :)

Comment: @DVK make sure you do so with google safesearch ***on***

Answer (score 11):

[The meaning of the name:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arwen#Literature)

> Arwen means Noble Maiden,Ar=noble,wen=maiden'.Arwen also known as the Evenstar (or Evening Star) was the youngest child of Elrond and Celebrían.

I think that the necklace represents Arwen's immortality in the movie. She gives it up for Aragorn, when she gives him the necklace.

[The meaning of the necklace:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arwen#Adaptations)

> The movies invent a jewelled pendant called the Evenstar which Arwen gives to Aragorn as a reminder of their love. In the novel, Aragorn and Arwen give a similar necklace to Frodo as a farewell gift before he leaves Minas Tirith.

Answer (score 7):

In the books, it was described that Arwen wore a "white jewel" upon her chest. She later gave it to Frodo when he leaves Minas Tirith to return to the Shire. He would often touch it or cling on to it whenever he ails about something (which happens during the anniversary of the day he got stabbed by the Morgul Blade, and the anniversary of the End of the War of Pellenor Fields), and most probably brought it with him to the Undying Lands.

Peter Jackson made the Evenstar necklace in reference to this white jewel, although it symbolizes more on her love for Aragorn... a Tolkien reference to a woman "giving her favor" to him, if you will. The Evenstar got it's name from Arwen herself, as she is called that by the elves of Rivendell in the books.

Answer (score 3):

The person who mentioned it as a gift to Frodo is right on the money. Someone read the book, great! In the book, it is described as "a white gem like a star that lay upon her breast hanging upon a silver chain".  This is clearly the Evenstar pendant (Evenstar being what her people lovingly called her).

Here is the entire reference from the book:

> But the Queen Arwen said: ‘A gift I will give you. For I am the daughter of Elrond. I shall not go with him now when he departs to the Havens: for mine is a choice of Luthien, and as she, so have I chosen both the sweet and the bitter. But in my stead you shall go, Ring-bearer, when the day comes, and if you then desire it. If your hurts grieve you, and the memory of your burden is heavy, then you may pass into the West, until all your wounds and weariness are healed. But wear this now in memory of Elfstone and Evenstar with whom your life has been woven!’
>
> And she took a white gem like a star that lay upon her breast hanging upon a silver chain, and she set the chain about Frodo’s neck. ‘When the memory of the fear and darkness troubles you,’ she said, ‘this will bring you aid.’

So the "white gem like a star" was also tied to giving Frodo her place on the ship to the Havens, and the gem was to give him relief until he found his healing in the West.

Jackson totally changed the meaning and purpose of the gift when she instead gave it to Aragorn as a symbol of undying love which does not stop at the end of life, as well as the sacrifice she made to stay with him. It was a surprise for me when I saw that in the movie, but also thought it beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

It symbolized hope, love, and immortality. Arwen gives it to Aragorn and she means that her love for him is more important than immortality.

Answer (score 0):

The Evenstar necklace symbolized love. Arwen gave it to Aragorn as a reminder of how much she loves him. It shows that nothing, not even her own immortality, is more important than her love for him. The necklace can also be seen as a symbol of hope. It was able to get Aragorn, and possibly Frodo, through tough times. I mention Frodo because it is possible that Arwen gave it to Frodo as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was made in Gondor, and then gifted to Galadriel, who later gifted it to her daughter, who then gifted it to Arwen, who later gave it to Aragorn

Comment: While this is all correct (except, I believe, the “made in Gondor part”) what is the necklace?